# Python code to retrieve absolute path of tomcat service

Tags: python, python-2.7, tomcat6

I am trying to write a python code that retrieves the absolute path of tomcat service by searching through the services with the service name in linux.
Is there any module i can use,
Code snipplets will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`psutil` is probably what you're looking for.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

```
import psutil

process_name = u'jboss'  # Place your case-insensitive process name here...
interesting_processes = []

# Loop over all processes, and see if process_name is in any segment of their command lines
for process in psutil.get_process_list():
    try:  # You cannot access some processes unless you're root, so we try here
        for cmd_segment in process.cmdline:
            if process_name.lower() in cmd_segment.lower():
                interesting_processes.append(process)
    except psutil.error.AccessDenied:
        continue  # processing other processes.

# Show off our results
for interesting_process in interesting_processes:
    print 'Process ID: {} has command: {}\n'.format(interesting_process.pid, u' '.join(interesting_process.cmdline))
```

In the above example, interesting_process.cmdline will be a list of arguments which make up the command line of your application.

HTH